# Given a Genomic Ranges of SNPs, how to inject these SNPs in genome via BSGenome?

Tags: r, bioconductor, reference-genome, snp, biostrings

Let's say I have the genome `hg19` loaded into R via BSGenome

```
library("BSgenome")    
hg19genome = getBSgenome('BSgenome.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19', masked=FALSE)
```

I then have a list of SNPs loaded as a GRanges object, `gr`

```
library(GenomicRanges)

 > gr
 GRanges object with 212 ranges and 3 metadata columns:                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        seqnames               ranges strand |     width     REF    ALT                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
           <Rle>          v <IRanges>  <Rle> | <numeric>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
    [1]        1 [86099032, 86099032]      * |         1     C      T                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
    [2]        1 [86099033, 86099033]      * |         1     C      A                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
    [3]        1 [86099199, 86099199]      * |         1     G      A  
  ....
```

Is there a straightforward way to inject these SNPs into `hg19genome`?

Comment: By inject you mean that the hg19genome should have the alternative base instead of the reference base for those positions?

Comment: @Llopis Yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems relatively complicated given the structure of a BSGenome object.

The creator of the package answered this question previously on the Bioconductor support forums:
https://support.bioconductor.org/p/86665/#86757

> We don't provide an easy way to inject arbitrary SNPs in an arbitrary
>   BSgenome at the moment. However, it should not be too hard to forge
>   the BSgenome ... package. First you would need to
>   compute the sequences of the mutated chromosomes (you can
>   use replaceLetterAt for this), then write them to a 2bit file (put
>   them in a DNAStringSet object and call rtracklayer::export on it),
>   then use that 2bit file to forge the BSgenome ....
>   package (see the BSgenomeForge vignette in the BSgenome package for
>   how to do this).
>   - Herve Pages

Here is another similar question with more info about replaceLetterAt: https://support.bioconductor.org/p/26199/

Comment: I noticed those. Question: can you think of another algorithmically efficient way to accomplish this? One way would be to convert the GRanges into a BED, then used this to create a new FASTA with the SNPS, and loaded this into BSGenome and then used `getSeq()`. That's very complicated though

Comment: I should mention that this is a section in the official documentation---the creators appears to have "not gotten around" to implementing this. See " Injecting known SNPs in the chromosome sequences" here: https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/BSgenome/inst/doc/GenomeSearching.pdf